# Change font awesome icon after click event

Tags: javascript

In the html, I have links to two font-awesome icons, a plus and a minus. I want the plus icon ONLY to load first.  When the plus icon is clicked, it runs a function and opens a vertical navigation bar. At this stage, I would like the plus icon to change to the minus.  Then, when the minus icon is clicked, the bar closes and the icon will change back to the plus.

This is the html:

```
 <nav>
     <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" style="font-size:20px;"></i></a>
     <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle" style="font-size:20px;"></i></a>
 </nav>
```

And this is the js:

```
var clicked = false;
$('.fa-plus-circle').click(function() {
    if (clicked == false) {
      $('div.vertical-nav').animate({
        'right': 0
      });
      clicked = true;

    } else {
      $('div.vertical-nav').animate({
        'right': -250
      });
      clicked = false;
    }

  });

})
```

Comment: What is your question then?

Comment: The question was how to toggle the icon with each click. My question has already been answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have two links and two icons, just change the icon (note I've added a neutral class, `toggler`):

```
<nav>
     <a href="#"><i class="fa toggler fa-plus-circle" style="font-size:20px;"></i></a>
</nav>
```

Then toggle the two classes, and they'll alternate (see `***` comments):

```
var clicked = false;
$('.toggler').click(function() { // ***
    if (clicked == false) {
        $('div.vertical-nav').animate({
            'right': 0
        });
        clicked = true;

    }
    else {
        $('div.vertical-nav').animate({
            'right': -250
        });
        clicked = false;
    }
    $(this).toggleClass("fa-plus-circle fa-minus-circle"); // ***
});
```

Example:

```js
var clicked = false;
$('.toggler').click(function() { // ***
    if (clicked == false) {
        $('div.vertical-nav').animate({
            'right': 0
        });
        clicked = true;

    }
    else {
        $('div.vertical-nav').animate({
            'right': -250
        });
        clicked = false;
    }
    $(this).toggleClass("fa-plus-circle fa-minus-circle"); // ***
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa toggler fa-plus-circle" style="font-size:20px;"></i></a>
</nav>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Side note: That function can be a lot simpler and doesn't need the `clicked` variable:

```
$('.toggler').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var toggled = $this.hasClass("fa-minus-circle");
    $('div.vertical-nav').animate({
        'right': toggled ? -250 : 0
    });
    $this.toggleClass("fa-plus-circle fa-minus-circle");
});
```

(Of course, you can keep `clicked` if you want it for something else...)

Example:

```js
$('.toggler').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var toggled = $this.hasClass("fa-minus-circle");
    $('div.vertical-nav').animate({
        'right': toggled ? -250 : 0
    });
    $this.toggleClass("fa-plus-circle fa-minus-circle");
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa toggler fa-plus-circle" style="font-size:20px;"></i></a>
</nav>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wow...that was so fast, and it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot. Super.

Comment: The simpler code as per your side does not work, however.

Comment: @jbm59er: Yes it does; I've added live examples to the answer. But you might want to add `return false` so that the page doesn't snap back to the top when the browser follows the `#` link.

Comment: Dear TD Crowder,  I didn't manage to get it to work.  This is my whole code (this is an exercise in class):-